# Multiplication of two factorials

Tags: linear-algebra, factorial

Please guide me whether the two sides are equal:
$$\Big(\frac{(2-a)b}{c}\Big)!*\Big(\frac{1}{c}\Big)!=\Big(\frac{(2-a)b+1}{c}\Big)!$$
where a, b and c are constants >0, Kindly prove this equation.

Comment: This is not clear.  The expressions aren't integers in general...do you mean to be using the Gamma Function?  Please give a numerical example of the phenomenon you think might be true in general.

Comment: You have $\frac1c!$ in there. What does that mean?

Comment: Just to say, even for integers it certainly isn't true that $n!\times m!=(n+m)!$.

Comment: The two sides are not equal when $a=b=c=1$.

Answer (score -1):

This is just an identity which I found in my research. Actually I am working on probability distribution and these are the parameters of it. I need to show this equation. One can show it by converting factorial to gamma function.

Comment: This a comment and not answer to your question.